# App user data and @facebook.com email addresses

Tags: facebook, email, message, user-permissions

My app collects users' basic information only as part of authentication (i.e. no extended permissions, and this data collection is non-revocable and can't be skipped), and as part of that authentication it will collect users' primary email addresses.

Since Facebook rolled out @facebook.com email addresses for all users, and set those as the default address published on users' pages, does this mean that the @facebook.com email addresses are now the primary email addresses for almost all users, and that my app will now collect the @facebook.com email address? Or will it still collect the email address provided by users when they signed-up to Facebook?

Comment: What have you found out in your own tests …?